# python don´t excecute when start container with crontab

Tags: docker, cron, cron-task, portainer, django-crontab

I try to execute a python when the container start.
I use crontab in the container:

```
crontab -l

@reboot python3.10 /opt/django/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
```

But when I stop and start container with portainer the python didn't execute

Comment: Normally the cron daemon doesn't run in a container. Try finding a tutorial on how to dockerize a Django app to get an idea of how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're trying to do this is not correct. Go to [python image page on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/python), get the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./your-daemon-or-script.py" ]
```

Then build your image. The script will start on container startup.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I could resolve the problem
I used the command:

```
docker run -it --name djangoapp -w /opt/django/ -p 8002:8002 <imagen>:1.0 python3.10 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8002
```